# UTC to local time conversion not working in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a UTC time to local timezone, but it doesn't seem to be converting it at all:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStringFromServer)!
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStringFromServer)!
```

The `dateStringFromServer` is a string representation of a UTC date. So I was expecting date1 to be in UTC, and date2 to be in PDT (my local time zone), but they are both the same. Something wrong with my syntax?

This is what I'm getting:

```
dateStringFromServer: 2016-10-21T05:24:26.000Z
date1: 2016-10-21 05:24:26 +0000
date2: 2016-10-21 05:24:26 +0000
```

How can I get date2 be in the device's local timezone?

Comment: do you mean the local time set on that particular device?

Comment: Yes the local time on the ios device

Comment: If you're expecting date1 to be UTC, then use timezone formatter for date1.
`dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")`

Comment: Actually more concerned about date2, which I want in the device's local timezone. How can I detect the local timezone?

Comment: You're doing wrong here, convert serverDate to UTC and then use that new date with your local time zone. It'll fix your issue.

Comment: @iOS10is my server date not in UTC according to the format you see?

Comment: Format doesn't define timezone. You've to specify that the time you getting from server is in UTC, like you did for date2 local time zone. Check my previous comment Ive added a line you can add that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126295/discussion-between-ios10-and-prabhu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert to the time zone set on the device you can do this

Swift3

```
    let dateFormatter =  DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStringFromServer)
    // return the timeZone of your device i.e. America/Los_angeles
    let timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier as String
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
    let date2 = dateFormatter.string(from: date1)
```

Swift2

```
     let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStringFromServer)
    // return the timeZone of your device i.e. America/Los_angeles
    let timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().name
   dateFormatter.timeZone =  NSTimeZone(name: timeZone)
    let date2 = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date1!)
```

Comment: Oh Sorry... you wanted swift 2...that was swift 3. I will update the code

Comment: @Prabhu please see the updated code. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It's the same because even though you think you're setting the date formatter's time zone to the current time zone *after* setting the first date, it doesn't matter. If you don't set the date formatter's time zone, it automatically sets to the system time zone as specified in Apple's docs for `NSDateFormatter`:

> If unspecified, the system time zone is used.

Therefore the date formatter's time zone is set to be the same both implicitly for the first date and explicitly for the second date because they happen to be identical, hence you're getting the same date back.

Comment: But regardless, at least both date1 and date2 should have been converted to PDT right? Why are both still in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code that work in swift4.**

```
 func UTCToLocal(date:String, fromFormat: String, toFormat: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = fromFormat
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = toFormat

    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}
```

> How to use :-

```
let localDateAsString = UTCToLocal(date: deadline!, fromFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", toFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a")
```